# jquery form validation is not working in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have done scripting in the same page

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

My form code

```
<form role="form" method="post" name="step1" id="step1" action="<?php echo site_url('Home/client_sign_up'); ?>">
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
   </div>       
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <input type="submit" name="client_submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
   </div>                                            
</form>
```

This code is not working
Scripting code

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};    
    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#step1").validate({
                rules: {
                    fname: "required",                 
                },
                messages: {
                    fname: "Please enter your firstname",                           
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }    
    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });    
})(jQuery, window, document);    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all I do. I havent looked at the latest version of validator , so this may not be up to date.

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$("#step1").validate({
    rules:{
        man: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        woman: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        year: {
            required: true,
            digit: true,
            maxlength: 4,
            minlength: 4
        },
        state: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 15
        },
        kids: {
            required: true,
            digit: true,
            maxlength: 2,
            minlength: 1
        },
        family: {
            required: true
        },
        relation: {
            required: true
        },
        family2: {
            required: true
        },
        male: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        man: {
            required: "Field Required",
            minlength: "5 of them please"
        },
        woman: {
            required: "Field Required",
            minlength: "5 of them please"
        },
        year: {
            required: "Field required",
            digit: "Digits only"
        },
        state: {
            required: "Field required",
            maxlength: "Answer too long"
        },
        kids: {
            required: "Field required",
            digit: "Gotta be numbers",
            maxlength: "Post too long"
        },
        family: {
            required: "This field required"
        },
        relation: {
            required: "This field required"
        },
        family2: {
            required: "This field required"
        },
        male: {
            required: "This field required"
        }
    }
  });
 });
```

The form looks like this. Its rather long

```
<?php $attr1 = array(
    'id' => "ajax",
    'class' => 'pure-form pure-form-aligned'
);?>
                <?php echo form_open('/forms/form1', $attr1) ;?>
                <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="family">Family</label>
                <?php
                    $attr2 = array(
                        '' => 'Pick one',
                        'Family' => 'family2',
                        'Family' => 'family1'
                    );
                echo form_dropdown("family", $attr2);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="male">Male</label>
                <?php
                $attr4 = array(
                    'name'      => 'male',
                    'maxlength' => '100',
                    'style'     => 'width:50%'
                );?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr4);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="female">FeMale</label>
                <?php
                $attr5 = array (
                    'name'      => 'female',
                    'maxlength' => '100',
                    'style'     => 'width:50%'
                );?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr5);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="branch2">2nd Branch</label>
                <?php
                $attr10 = array (
                    'name'        => 'branch2',
                    'maxlength'   => '100',
                    'style'       => 'width:50%',
                    'placeholder' => "Other family branch start"
                );?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr10);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="relationship">Relationship</label>
                <?php
                $attr6 = array(
                    'name'      => 'relationship',
                    'maxlength' => '100',
                    'style'     => 'width:50%'
                );?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr6);?> <span>8th Great Grandfather</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="relative">Relative From Ancestry</label>
                <?php
                $attr7 = array (
                    'name'        => 'relative',
                    'maxlength'   => '100',
                    'placeholder' => "Ancestry Relative",
                    'style'       => 'width:50%'
                );?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr7);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="level">Cousin Level</label>
                <?php
                $attr8 = array (
                    'name'      => 'level',
                    'maxlength' => '2',
                    'type'      => 'number'
                );?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr8);?> <span><u>3</u>rd cousin</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="Year">Year Born</label>
                <?php
                $attr9 = [
                    'name'      => 'year',
                    'maxlength' => '4',
                    'type'      => 'number'
                ];?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr9);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="country">Country of Birth</label>
                <?php
                $attr11 = [
                    'name'      => 'country',
                    'maxlength' => '100',
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'id' => 'country'
                ];?>
                <?php echo form_input($attr11);?>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                <br>
                <?php
                $attr12 = [
                    'name' => 'comment',
                    'id'   => 'comment'
                ];?>
                <?php echo form_textarea($attr12);?>
                </div>
            <div class="pure-controls"> 
            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
            echo form_reset('reset', 'Reset');
            echo form_close();?>
```

The controller

```
public function form1() //insert family ancestry
{
    $data = array (
        'family'        => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('family'))),
        'male'          => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('male'))),
        'female'        => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('female'))),
        'relationship' =>  htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('relationship'))),
        'relative'      => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('relative'))),
        'level'         => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('level'))),
        'year'          => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('year'))),
        'branch2'       => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('branch2'))),
        'country'       => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('country'))),
        'comment'       => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('comment')))

    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('family', 'Family', 'required|alpha|max_length[9]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('male', 'Male', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('female', 'Female', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('relationship', 'Relationship', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('relative', 'Relative', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('level', 'Level', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch2', 'Branch 2', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'required|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'trim');
    if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();
    }else
    {
        $this->db->insert('primary', $data);
        echo "All is well.";
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please share me the your html form